# Prestashop giving admin url error on installing https

Tags: php, prestashop

I have activate https on my ecommerce website using prestashop. Once I have activated the same the website is working fine. But when I open the admin url it is showing me error

> **SSL is activated. Please connect using the following URL to log in secure mode**.

Screen shot is attached here. Please if any one can help me solve the same.[image]

Comment: See here : [prestashop-forums](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/159044-solved-ssl-is-activated-please-connect-using-the-following-url-to-log-in-in-secure-mode-https/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do deactivate and activate the ssl security in Backend

Comment: .htaccess is changed?

Comment: cache is empty?